# a variant of MLE of a normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

It is well-known that if we have "n" sample observations from normal distribution with unknown mean, then the sample mean would be the MLE for the mean of the normal distribution.

However, let's assume that before we collect our sample, somebody has already collected "n" sample observations, and the only information we get from that guy is that all the "n" sample observations were smaller or equal to A for some real number A.

Is there any way we could somehow use "n" and "A" into MLE for the mean when we collect our sample?

Any input would be greatly appreciated. I'm just curious.

Comment: Can anyone with a Bayesian background answer this? Try adding that tag as well.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to combine your data with the previous sample (called censored data) and apply maximum likelihood. Look up survival analysis.